# CSS - Center content that's wider than the page

Tags: css

Here's a simple puzzle that's been frustrating me for a while today:

Consider this page markup:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrapper { overflow: hidden; }
        #content { width: 750px; height: 100px; background: orange; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="content">Foo bar</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I get `div#content` centered in the page *regardless of viewport width*?

I've tried a variety of tricks (including `text-align: center; display: inline-block;`) and absolute positioning, but with all of them the `div#content` is left-aligned when the browser window is brought under 750px in width.

I've seen a few high-profile websites do this in the past. For example on Apple.com when they advertised the new retina iPad: the iPad pictured was a very wide image that extended past the main page area (note it was not a CSS background image of the `<body>` element), but it didn't cause scrolling when the browser window only fit the main page content. Unfortunately I can't seem to find any existing sites that do this so I can't find a reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this it? Take a look -> http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/CkvuG/

HTML

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="main">
      <div id="extended-out"><img src="http://myfreeipad.us.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/ipad.png" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#page {
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 200px; /*same as #mains width*/
}

#main{
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}


#extended-out { 
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 -100px;
  background: indianred;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#extended-out img {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

​

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/CNNcV/

```
<head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #wrapper { overflow: hidden; }
            #content { width: 750px; height: 100px; background: orange; 
            margin:0px auto;
            width:100%;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="content">Foo bar</div>
        </div>
    </body>​
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No, because when the browser viewport is narrower than 750px the left edge of `div#content` is aligned with the left edge of the viewport rather than being beyond it.

Answer (score -1):

Add `margin: auto` to this,

```
#content { width: 750px; height: 100px; background: orange; margin: auto}
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. It only centres `div#content` when the browser viewport is wider than 750px; When the viewport is narrower than 750px the element's left edge is on contact with the viewport's left edge. I want the horizontal middle of `div#content` to always be aligned with the horizontal middle of the viewport (assuming no scrolling, hence the `overflow: hidden;` in my CSS).

Comment: To better understand you, you mean the height should be the same when the browsers viewport is narrower than 750px?

Comment: Height is irrelevant. I'm after horizontal alignment, not vertical.